# How to select a particular <SPAN> of same class under different <DIV>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having different span with same class for different control...
How can I select a particular span for associate  control at a time.Should I use diff span id for every span.

Comment: Can you show your HTML code associated?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the markup in your question to demonstrate, and then point out which element you want to select?

Comment: <body>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return Validatefun()" id="contactform" name="myform">

<div>
<label id="name">Name</Label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name">
<span class="error" id="nm">*This field is required</span>
</div>

<div>
<label id="mail">Email</Label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="mail">
<span class="error"  id="cl">*This field is required</span>
</div>
</form>

Comment: .error {
display: none;
margin-left: 10px;
} 

.error_show {
color : #FF0000;
margin-left: 10px;
}

Comment: want to validate each field but not to use jquery

Answer (score 3):

If you have multiple DIVs containing SPANs:

```
<div>
    <span>Text 1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span>Text 2</span>
</div>
```

There are many, many ways you can can select them individually.

Here are a few:

### Assigning IDs to elements

**You can either assign the DIVs IDs and select them as follows:**

```
<div id="first">
    <span>Text 1</span>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <span>Text 2</span>
</div>
```

*CSS selectors:*

```
#first span { /* Add style rules here! */ }
#second span { /* Add style rules here! */ }
```

*Selecting with jQuery:*

```
var first = $('#first span');
var second = $('#second span');
```

**Or give the spans IDs and select them as follows:**

```
<div>
    <span id="first">Text 1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span id="second">Text 2</span>
</div>
```

*CSS selectors:*

```
#first { /* Add style rules here! */ }
#second { /* Add style rules here! */ }
```

*Selecting with jQuery:*

```
var first = $('#first');
var second = $('#second');
```

### Assigning Classes to elements

**As with IDs, assign identifying classes to DIVs:**

```
<div class="first">
    <span>Text 1</span>
</div>
<div class="second">
    <span>Text 2</span>
</div>
```

*CSS selectors:*

```
.first span { /* Add style rules here! */ }
.second span { /* Add style rules here! */ }
```

*Selecting with jQuery:*

```
var first = $('.first span');
var second = $('.second span');
```

**Or assign classes to the Spans:**

```
<div>
    <span class="first">Text 1</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="second">Text 2</span>
</div>
```

*CSS selectors:*

```
.first { /* Add style rules here! */ }
.second { /* Add style rules here! */ }
```

*Selecting with jQuery:*

```
var first = $('.first');
var second = $('.second');
```

### Using the `:nth-child()` selector:

For this, we need to modify the markup to include a parent element that we can select:

```
<article>
    <div>
        <span>Text 1</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Text 2</span>
    </div>
<article>
```

**And then we can select a child of `article` by using `article:nth-child(n)`:**

*CSS selectors:*

```
article:nth-child(1) span { /* Add style rules here! */ }
article:nth-child(2) span { /* Add style rules here! */ }
```

*Selecting with jQuery:*

```
var first = $('article:nth-child(1) span');
var second = $('article:nth-child(2) span');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, just do it like this:

```
$('span[class="yourclassname"]')
```

Comment: have to use JS only and using same class for every span

Comment: How about get all dom with the class `"yourclass"` using `document.getElementsByClassName("yourclass")` and then filter these doms to see if they are `span`?

Comment: still i have to select particular span ,one at a time and then  adding or removing class according to condition.

Comment: .error {
display: none;
margin-left: 10px;
} 

.error_show {
color : #FF0000;
margin-left: 10px;
}

Comment: even used document.getElementById()...bt doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

If your control in which you are having span have different ids or tags then you can find the span like $('#controlId span.commonClass') or $('controlTag span.commonClass'). For clear information please provide your html.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can find using J query following code will help you

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
           $(function () {                    
               var Span = $("#ControlID .SpanClass");
           });
   </script>
```

Comment: Have to write the code through JS only