# How to set styles to a slotted element in a template tag

Tags: html, css, sass

```
<template id="element-details-template">
        <link href="./src/components/lit-button/button.scss" rel="stylesheet">
    <svg ..</svg>
    <span slot="buttonLabel">span1</span>
    <span class="name" slot="buttonSubLabel">span2</span>
</template>
```

I want to style just the second span in an external css file. But the styles are not getting affected/reflected. I am confused as to what the problem might be?
The below code is my css:

```
:host {
  #element-details-template {
    span.name {
      text-transform:lowercase;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I guess [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32009578/18799650) is what you asked for

Comment: @g78 Thank for your reply. Unfortunately, no. The example you have put is for normal html elements. These are slotted elements and I am unabled to apply the css styles that I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the class is in an external css file (like the global one styles.css, or a parent one) just try removing the :host directive. To be sure it should affect the span element, use also !important directive. You can also specify the only class/classes you want to affect with the css class like:

(if the class were there's the html code is called for example "test.html")

```
app-test{
  #element-details-template{
    span.name {
      text-transform:lowercase !important;
    }
  }
}
```

While if you want this class to affect the entire application (if you put this css class in the styles.css) when you use those id and class name, you can remove the app-test block:

```
#element-details-template{
   span.name {
      text-transform:lowercase !important;
   }
}
```

I tried and with the :host block it didn't work but in this way it should work. Hope it's helpful :)